# How can I set Vim up to search for and sort all lines containing a certain string?

Tags: regex, vim, organization, todo, vimgrep

I am using vim to manage a to-do list, and would like to set a hotkey to do the following:

1. Find all lines which contain the word under the cursor. The world is always a tag formatted as: #mytaghere
2. Sort all of these lines alphabetically by another tag contained within them. Again the tag is in #mytaghere format. For example, all lines with the tag #priorityA would be alphabetized and placed above all lines with the tag #priorityB, and so on.
3. Put all of these lines into Vim's quickfix window.

I have managed to achieve a limited version of 1 and 3 by putting the following into my .vimrc file:

```
map <f2> :vimgrep <cword> % <bar> copen <enter>
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,95,35 "lets cword include #s and _s
```

This setup fails whenever the word under the cursor contains a #, and it works whenever the character is something else (for example, an _ ) The error produced is: "E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter" which seems like the # is interfering with vimgrep.

Also, I can't figure out how to sort the lines by priority tags.

Thanks in advance for any help. I am just learning Vim, and if I could just get this problem solved I'd be able to use it for all of my organizing.

Comment: It's probably best to use delimiters around the vimgrep pattern, `:vimgrep /<cword>/ % ...`. Also, `:sort //` might be of use here.

Comment: There are many todo plugins on vim.org. Did you try any of them?

Comment: I did look at a few different plugins, as well well as a few different proprietary programs. All I really need, however, is the ability to search for tags and sort the results. The simpler I can keep my solution the better.

Answer (score 1):

The `:vimgrep` command comes in two forms:

> ```
> :vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
> :vim[grep][!] {pattern} {file} ...
> ```

For `/{pattern}/`, actually any non-keyword delimiter can be used. When your `<cword>` starts with `#`, Vim interprets this as the start delimiter, then complains because there's no end delimiter.

Choose a delimiter and put it around `<cword>`; to make the search literal, use `\V` and escape the current word, which is now inserted though the expression register `=`:

```
:noremap <f2> :vimgrep /<C-r>='\V'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\')<CR>/ % <bar> copen <enter>
```

Oh, and [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! This works perfectly to find all of my tags and put them in the quickfix window. Now I'm just stuck on how to sort them. Using :sort sorts by line number, because that's what is listed first in the line in the quickfix window after the file name:

    Dropbox/todo.txt|100 col 34| The actual line to sort is here

So I'm trying to define a range to exclude everything after the second |, but none of my range definitions are working

Comment: The quickfix window is special, you cannot just modify it like another buffer. You can get and manipulate the items with the `getqflist()` and `setqflist()` functions, though.

Comment: But, after I run 'set modifiable' and then 'sort' the list itself is sorted, just according to the wrong text. It even asks if I want to save when I try to close the buffer.

In other words, I guess what I'm asking is how to use 'sort' in a way that ignores anyFileNameHere.txt|anyTextHere|

Comment: You can skip a leading `{pattern}` with `:sort`, have you tried passing that?!

Comment: Yes, however none of the patterns that I have used have worked to ignore everything except the line itself. I apologize for my ignorance - I'm reading the vim documentation for patterns as well as searching online. I simply don't know how to construct the proper pattern.

Comment: Well, if you can't find a proper pattern yourself, I'd suggest to submit another question, with a proper example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: After a bunch of Googleing I found a page explaining the patterns and got it to work. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Glad I could help. The help is excellent and has all the information at `:help pattern`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ingo Karkat I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
noremap <f2> :vimgrep /<C-r>='\V'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\')<CR>/ % <bar> copen <enter>
```

The above will take everything under the cursor and put it into the quickfix window.

```
:set modifiable
:sort /.*|.*|/
```

The above will sort everything in the quick fix window ignoring the file name and line/column information.

To do everything at once (find all tagged lines and sort them by the first character of those lines):

```
noremap <f2> :vimgrep /<C-r>='\V'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\')<CR>/ % <bar> copen <enter> <bar> :set modifiable <enter> <bar> :sort /.*\|.*\|/ <enter>
```